# Google Meet Android app crash when new meeting link is opened via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, crash-reports, google-meet

On Android 11, 10 and lower, the google meet app does not handle the runtime permission defined in it's resolved activity `com.google.android.libraries.communications.conference.ui.intents.AssistantNewUrlHandlerActivity`

This can be easily reproduced with following code:

```kotlin
​private fun openGoogleMeetUrl() {
    val url = "https://meet.google.com/new"

    val webpage: Uri = Uri.parse(url)
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage)
    val resolveActivity = intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)

    if (resolveActivity != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Log.w("DEBUG_TAG", "Unable to find activity to launch.")
    }
}
```

Hoping someone from the app team has tag subscription to be notified. If anybody knows a workaround to this crash, let me know. Thanks

**Additional Details: https://support.google.com/meet/thread/187185694**

---

Crash log:

```
8199-8199/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chromecustomtab, PID: 8199
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://meet.google.com/... cmp=com.google.android.apps.meetings/com.google.android.libraries.communications.conference.ui.intents.AssistantNewUrlHandlerActivity } from ProcessRecord{ea9c15f 8199:com.example.chromecustomtab/u0a152} (pid=8199, uid=10152) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3851)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1705)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at com.example.chromecustomtab.MainActivity.openWithUrlIntent(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at com.example.chromecustomtab.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at com.example.chromecustomtab.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$z3Mks0G0-clLlQbj_fjGy_IFcVM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.chromecustomtab.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:760)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:583)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1288)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:514)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the runtime exception that is crashing the app is from 3rd party application. Not much can be done.

The workaround, for now, is to handle the issue like following:

```kotlin
try {
    openGoogleMeetUrl()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open url", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```